# Python 2.7 re search and findall providing different search results

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am trying to extract all function calls from a line of code and put then into a list of strings.  For example, the string:

```
z = x + cos(x + y) - sin(x+2) + 3;
```

should be parsed into

```
['cos(x+y)','sin(x+2)']
```

Using python 2.7's `re.search` function and the regular expression

```
searchString = '([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])+?[(].*?[)]'
```

I can extract the first function, `cos(x+y)`, as expected.

When I use `findall` instead, I do get a list of two strings, but they contain only the characters just before the `(`.  That is, I get `['s','n']`

Since my regex works with `search`, what did I do wrong with `findall`?

The function I'm using is:

```
'''Separates out all function calls'''
def separateFunctionCalls(str):
    searchString = "([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])+?[(].*?[)]"
    grp = re.findall(searchString,str)
    usingSearch = re.search(searchString,str)
    print usingSearch.group(0)
    print grp
```

And the test code is:

```
str = "return 2*cos(x+y) + sin(x+2)+1.0;"
separateFunctionCalls(str)
```

Comment: Try just `[(].*?[)]`

Comment: I need the function's name as well, though

Comment: Ah ok, try it like this `[^\s()]+\([^()]+\)` See https://regex101.com/r/Vnq6DT/1

Comment: Yes, that works just fine, thanks!  What was wrong with my original one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern uses an alternation of character classes without a quantifier which will match only 1 of the listed items.

When you repeat a capturing group, the group contains the value of the last iteration, that is why you see those matches.

You could write the character class as a single one containing all the ranges and repeat that instead:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+\([^()]+\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vnq6DT/2)

To match your values you might also match not a whitespace char or parenthesis, then match from the opening till closing parenthesis to get for example a bit broader match

```
[^\s()]+\([^()]+\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vnq6DT/1)

Comment: So if I understood it, your pattern instead matches all things that *are not* a valid function name followed by parentheses.  Instead, my pattern tried to search for a specific pattern?  I'm still not entirely clear why my original idea didn't work with findall, but the pattern you gave worked.  I did modify it to also exclude operators so that, for instance, `2*cos(x)` extracts the `cos(x)` without the `2*`, but that became evident only after testing

Comment: Your pattern works if you change the capturing group to a non capturing one `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\(.*?\)` because findall will give you the values in the capturing group. Note that you don't have to use an alternation for the character classes but you can just use 1 character class.

Comment: @Stachowsky I have added an update with an explanation. You can omit the non capturing group at all.

Comment: Yes indeed.  I've tested both versions now and they produce the same results